# Javascript Substring comparison; am I crazy?

Tags: javascript, substring

From my understanding, JavaScript's substring methods takes two parameters: first one is the index from where to start, and the second is the end point (non-index type counting, aka number of chars not 0-starting) which does not include the end-point char. Following this logic, I ran two examples:

This first example bellow worked as expected, I counted 13 chars because the 13th char was the end point and was not going to be included.

```
// goal was to print "Melbourne is"
alert("Melbourne is great".substring(0,13));
```

This example however failed. In this example I also stopped my count at the end point because I expected it not to be counted.

```
//goal was to print "Jan"
alert("January".substring(0,4));
```

Where is my understanding flawed?

Comment: [`String.prototype.substring(indexStart[, indexEnd])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring): "_indexEnd: Optional. An integer between 0 and the length of the string, which specifies the offset into the string of the first character not to include in the returned substring._"

Comment: In the first example, you are actually printing "Melbourne is " with a final space.

Comment: Why was this question down-voted?

Comment: @brooklynsweb Because SO can be that way sometimes.

Comment: @brooklynsweb Also, to better explain indexes in javascript, they are almost always zero based.  So in your string ("January"), "J" is at index 0, the first "a" is at 1.  The reason why `"January".substring(0,4)` returns "Janu" is because it starts at index 0 (which is "J") and ends at index 4 (which is the second "a").  `.substring()` is exclusive rather than inclusive.  That means the "a" is excluded from the return.  The result is "Janu".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are going crazy is because the function

```
alert("Melbourne is great".substring(0,13)); 
//prints Melbourne_is_ not Melbourne_is
```

Notice the space after

Don't go crazy! :)

Answer (score 7):

> JavaScript's substring methods takes two parameters: first one is the index from where to start, and the second is the end point (non-index type counting, aka number of chars not 0-starting) which does not include the end-point char

You are incorrect in this understanding.  You are describing the functonality of [`.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).  [`.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) uses two indexes.